# Can I make this countdown work in only one function?

Tags: javascript

This code works fine (It is a countdown for a project I'm doing), but i want to do it with only one function. It is possible?

```
function workingCountdown(){
    //Set an interval that call the countdown function every second
    window.variableCountdown = setInterval(countdown, 1000)
}
function countdown(){
    //CHECK IF SECONDS IS BIGGER THAN ONE
    if(seconds>1){
        //IF YES
        //Substract 1 to the seconds variable
        window.seconds--
        //Change the countdown text according to seconds left
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "You have " + seconds + " seconds left"
    } else {
        //IF NO
        //Notify the user that they ran out of time by changing the countdown text
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "You have 0 seconds left"
        //Let pass fifty miliseconds so the countdown text can change before the alert is played
        setTimeout(function(){cpsTestFinish()}, 50) 
        //Stop the countdown repeat
        clearInterval(variableCountdown)
    }
}
```

Comment: this actual countdown can't work, you are using delay value for counting seconds!

Comment: What is `seconds`, what is `cpsTestFinish`. And you should show the actual problem you have in merging the two functions.

Comment: You can just make the `countdown()` function an anonymous function that you put in the call to `setInterval()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise the counter in the main function. If it reaches zero call the other function, otherwise log the count, and call the function again passing in the reduced count.

```js
const countdown = document.querySelector('#countdown');

function fn() {
  countdown.innerHTML = `You ran out of time!`;
}

function timer(seconds = 5) {
  if (seconds === 0) {
    fn();
  } else {
    countdown.innerHTML = `You have ${seconds} seconds left`;
    setTimeout(timer, 1000, --seconds);
  }
}

timer();
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: nice answer, not too fond of `!seconds` tho.

Comment: Just for you I changed it @Onheiron.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
function countdown(remaining) {
  if(remaining > 0) {
    // update the remaining time UI
    console.log(`Remaining ${remaining}`);
    setTimeout(() => countdown(remaining - 1), 1000)
  } else {
    // do whatever you need to do when the countdown is over
    console.log("DONE");
  }
}
// then you call
countdown(10)
```

This also displays a "Remaining" at the very start so the user is notified with the actual starting seconds.

Also you don't need to keep any reference to the interval or `window` variables.